# AJAX: multiple file upload separately

Tags: javascript

I'm configuring a multiple file upload with Jquery and Ajax, here the source code.
HTML:

```
<div id="dropzone-zone">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="add_file" name="add_file" form="upload-form" style="display:none;">Subir archivos</button>
    <form action="" id="upload-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="dropzone" class="drop-zone" style="display:none;">
            <span class="drop-zone__prompt">Haga click o arrastre los archivos que desea subir.</span>
            <input type="file" name="file-upload[]" style="display:none;" id="file-upload" class="drop-zone__input" multiple>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const inputElement = document.getElementById("file-upload");
const dropZoneElement = document.getElementById("dropzone");
dropZoneElement.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => { e.preventDefault(); });
dropZoneElement.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    inputElement.files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    dropZoneElement.querySelector(".drop-zone__prompt").remove();

    for(var i=0; i<inputElement.files.length; i++) {
        var file = inputElement.files[i];
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file-upload", file);
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (event){
            if(event.lengthComputable){
                var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
                document.getElementById("load-progress").value = Math.round(percent);
            }
        }, false);
        ajax.open("POST", "pruebas.php");
        ajax.send(formdata);
    }
    //document.getElementById('add_file').click();
});
```

With this code, I want that with more than one file, first proccesses the first file, uploading to the location defined in pruebas.php, and meanwhile, completing the progress bar.
After the first file, starts with the second file, uploading it and completing its bar.
And the third and the fourth, etc; until all have been completed, then the form is being submitted and the redirect is done.

Now it's working, I mean it uploads the files to the server, but I can't proccess the upload progress bar because it doesn't wait for the end of the first upload, and I don't know how can evaluate the end of the upalods to determine when I have to submit the form.

Can someone explain me what do I have to change, or some post related?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Moved the possible Solution into an Answer, see below.

Comment: You are at no point using jQuery in the code you posted, I removed this from your questino + tag.

Answer (score 0):

[`XMLHttpRequest.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open#syntax) is asnychronous by default. This means, that the Request is sent and the code is not halted. You can set the property in `.open(METHOD, URL, ASYNC)` async to false, therefore the `.send()` method wont return until the response is recieved. This would cause the for-loop to wait for the Upload to finish.

I've edited your code below, I simply added another parameter to `.open()` which determines of the Method should be executed asynchronously.

```js
const inputElement = document.getElementById("file-upload");
const dropZoneElement = document.getElementById("dropzone");
dropZoneElement.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => { e.preventDefault(); });
dropZoneElement.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    inputElement.files = e.dataTransfer.files;
    dropZoneElement.querySelector(".drop-zone__prompt").remove();

    for(var i=0; i<inputElement.files.length; i++) {
        var file = inputElement.files[i];
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file-upload", file);
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (event){
            if(event.lengthComputable){
                var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
                document.getElementById("load-progress").value = Math.round(percent);
            }
        }, false);


        // Changed the parameter for 'async' to false
        ajax.open("POST", "pruebas.php", false);


        ajax.send(formdata);
    }
    //document.getElementById('add_file').click();
});
```